# How to apply Speller from autocorrect to a specific column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I tried this:

```
from autocorrect import Speller

spell = Speller(lang='en')
df['Text'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda x: spell(x))
```

But I get the error: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably some of the values in `df['Text']` are neither `str` nor `bytes`. Try this:

```
from autocorrect import Speller

spell = Speller(lang='en')
df['Text'] = df['Text'].apply(
    lambda x: spell(x) if isinstance(x, str) or isinstance(x, bytes) else x)
```

Comment: It gives a synthax error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax. It works now since the if was missing: df['Text'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda x: spell(x) if x is isinstance(x, str) or isinstance(x, bytes) else x)

Comment: sorry about the typo, `is` was indeed an `if`

Comment: @user546546846413 if this solved your issue, remember to click "accept" on the answer